# How can I embed a Prolog-like inference engine into a .NET application?

Tags: .net, prolog, inference-engine

Certain kinds of domain logic are represented more naturally using Prolog predicates than C# objects. One example of such a domain is [representing family relationships](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog#Evaluation).

Is there a way to embed a Prolog-like inference engine into a .NET application? It would be nice to use inferences to drive my domain but traditional OO in the rest of my application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one: [Prolog.NET](http://prolog.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Hope not too late! Try [tuProlog.NET](https://bitbucket.org/tuprologteam/tuprolog). I use it in Java and love it!